# Comparison of two different models usig the same CV partition

Tags: r, model-comparison, partitioning

I am trying to compare two different models with cross validation and I am not sure whether I choosed an effective way to split my dataset into equal sized partitions. My data frame is called  `anne` and I tried this before the loop:

```
anne<-anne[sample(nrow(anne)),]
my_folds<- cut(seq(1,nrow(anne)),breaks=10,labels=FALSE)
```

Since I want to do comparisons of different models the partions are very important.

*Question 1.*

Is this a good way to create my partitions?

*Question 2.*

Is it better if I use the `createDataPartition` from  `caret` package?

(e.g `createDataPartition(anne$response, p=.80, list=FALSE`)

ps. I also used the `set.seed`